# Login Issue to Azure AD B2C

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have list of users in Azure Active Directory with different sources as shown in image
[image]

I cannot be able to login to with users with `External Azure Active Directory` as a source. I am using `angular-oauth2-oidc` module to authorize a user. This is the error i get whenever i login with user with source `External Azure Active Directory`
[image]

Comment: Hi, do you have a chance to look into my answer? If you have any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @AllenWu thanks. It worked. It helped me alot... I need help in another part. Can you help me?

Comment: If it's a further question, you can just update your post. If it is a different question, it is better to open another post.

Comment: BTW,  if my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. Thank you.

Comment: @AllenWu i just posted another question can you please check here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61234596/not-prompting-change-password-on-first-signin

Comment: @AllenWu i will accept it after implementing it, haven't tried it yet as i got busy with Graph API

Comment: @AllenWu can you please check another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61681648/the-preferred-replica-is-unavailable-microsoft-graph

Answer (score 1):

Users with `External Azure Active Directory` are guest users invited into the Azure AD B2C.

They are not the [local account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview#consumer-user) of the Azure AD B2C. So you can't log in with these users.

You can verify the `identities` property through Microsoft Graph API: `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{Object ID}`. You will find there are no `emailAddress` or `userName` in it.

If you want to log in with them, you should configure sign-in for a specific Azure Active Directory.

You can refer to [Set up sign-in for a specific Azure Active Directory under User Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant) and [Set up sign-in with an Azure Active Directory account using custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=applications).