# The preferred replica is unavailable - Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

While creating user using `microsoft graph`,it was working fine yesterday but now I am getting the error below.

```
    "error": {
        "code": "Directory_ReplicaUnavailable",
        "message": "The preferred replica is unavailable. Please retry your request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "19030bd0-0aad-49cf-9d40-6fcb7fb4360e",
            "date": "2020-05-08T14:35:45"
        }
    }
```

Comment: This seems to be transient issue. Please retry after few hours ,the API should started working normally.

Comment: @UJJAVAL123-MSFTIdentity my azure-ad-b2c subscriptions status is `Subscription status
:
Suspended`

Comment: you shall reactivate the subscription for usage. For subscription issue ,Create a support request here. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083458

Comment: @UJJAVAL123-MSFTIdentity i reactivated the subscription and hit the same endpoint still getting same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Subscription will not affect operations against Azure AD, such as creating users.

It should be an issue with Microsoft service side. Please have a retry after a few hours.